# It is difficult to handle multiple dimension list with tcl

Tags: multidimensional-array, tcl, tk-toolkit

I need to handle kind of complex data with tcl. I need 3 dimension list to store the data, 
but I find tcl is bad for this work.

Based on my current study, tcl does not support simple index of list like: listname(index).

So for multiple dimension list, if I want  to assign a new value for certain element, it will be very troubling.

Are there some skills to handling data effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient representation for a multi-dimensional array is a nested list (unless you're going for a sparse array). To help with this, you have `lrepeat` for creation, multi-index `lindex` for reading, and `lset` for writing.

```
# Create a 5x5x5 structure, filled with float zeroes
set example [lrepeat 5 [lrepeat 5 [lrepeat 5 0.0]]]
```

```
# Index into the structure
set value [lindex $example 1 2 3]
```

```
# Write a value back into the structure
lset example 1 2 3 [expr {$value + 8.75}]
```

The implementation uses an efficient copy-on-write scheme for lists (including nested lists) so that you get space-saving where possible and minimal duplication where necessary in order to maintain the illusion that it's all a pure value with aggressive copying. Except much faster…

Of course, if you're doing this a lot, you might be better off having a look at [VecTcl](http://auriocus.github.io/VecTcl/).

Comment: ，thank you. I will try, it sounds good. Now I use very basic way to handle reading and writing for multiple list. When the data is big, it is too slow to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want listname(index), you can also try arrays instead.  Multi dimensional arrays are easy, as you can simply set your index as appropriate:

```
set example(1,2,3) $value
set value $example(1,2,3)
```

I don't know which would be more efficient, arrays, lists as in Donal's example or a dictionary:

```
dict set example 1 2 3 $value
set value [dict get $example 1 2 3]
```