# Getting columns values in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am trying to capture some data in TCL. I have below data :
{0.0 0.0} {0.741 0.48}
My required out put is 3rd column of this data.
0.741
how can i achieve it?

```
set oaDesign [ed]
set rprb [db::getShapes -of $oaDesign -lpp {INST_B drawing}] 
set r [de::getBBox  $rprb]
puts $r
{0.0 0.0} {0.741 0.48}
```

I just need 3rd column, which is 0.741

Comment: Judging by that output, `$r` is a list containing two elements, each of which is a two-element list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `lindex` and `lset`, respectively, to access the nested list's elements at a known position:

```
 % lindex $r 1 0
 0.741
```

To write back into that list of lists, at a given position:

```
 % lset r 1 0 0.0
 {0.0 0.0} {0.0 0.48}
```

Did you search SO for [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378982/it-is-difficult-to-handle-multiple-dimension-list-with-tcl/26379904#26379904), before raising your question?

Comment: It worked for me, but i do not understand , how.. suppose i need 0.048 then what do i need to put ?

Comment: Did you check the manual for [`lindex`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm) and [`lset`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm)? The former says: "If additional index arguments are supplied, then each argument is used in turn to select an element from the previous indexing operation, allowing the script to select elements from sublists." See the examples on the manpages!